# Eigenvalues of compact operator from the eigenvalues of the sequence of the approximating finite rank operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

It is know that if $T$ is a compact operator on an Hilbert space, then there exists a succession of finite rank operator $T_n$ that converges to $T$. Suppose that there exists $N$ and $\lambda$ such that $\lambda\in\sigma(T_n) \forall n>N$ (so $\lambda$ should be an eigenvalue, being the operators of  finite rank). Then, we can write an expression of type:
$$
T_nx_n=\lambda x_n \forall n>N
$$
Can we conclude that $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $T$? (The main problem for me is how to handle with the $x_n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True if $\lambda \neq 0$. We may suppose $\|x_n\|=1$ for all $n$. We have $\|\lambda x_n-Tx_n\| \leq \|T-T_n\| \to 0$.  Since $T$ is compact there is subsequence of $(Tx_n)$ which converges in the norm. But then the corresponding subsequence of $(x_n)$ itself converges. If $x$ is the limit of this subsequence then $Tx=\lambda x$. Also, $\|x\|=1$, so $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is it possibile to say something about 0? Maybe could we conclude that it is part of continuous/residual spectrum? (even if I don't know if it is possible to have a non empty residual spectrum for a compact operator)